# Tableview's cells are always empty

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Tableview's cells are empty. I've tried multiple times and it always produces empty cells for my tableview.

Any help please?
Thank you.

```
import UIKit

class GroupsTableViewController: UITableViewController /* UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate */ {


@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!


var items=["Dog","Cat","Cow","Platypus"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.table.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    self.table.dataSource = self
    self.table.delegate = self

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) ->         Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection  section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return items.count
}



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel!.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}

       override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("You tapped on cell # \(indexPath.row)")
}
```

Comment: `numberOfSectionInTableView` must at least be 1

Comment: I thought "self.table.dataSource = self" meant that it was.

Comment: @lee thank you, i feel stupid for not paying attention lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) ->         Int {
// #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
return 1
}
```

Comment: Or remove the function completely since it defaults to 1 if not implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You have given `return 0` in `numberOfSectionsInTableView` method.
`numberOfSectionsInTableView` should return value grater than `1`.

If you have only one `section` in `UITableView` then you can remove this method because default it will display only on `section` in `UITableView`.

or you can try this.

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) ->         Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}
```